# Calculate difference in log odds between two logistic regression models

Tags: probability, logistic, logarithm, odds

I would like to calculate the difference in log-odds between the error of two logistic regression models, given the correct answer aka ground truth (depression present${}= 1;$ depression absent${} = 0$) and the predicted probabilities of depression being present from each model (pA and pB).

I believe the formulas are as follows:

When the correct answer is that depression is present:
$$=(\log(1) - \log(1-pA)) - (\log(1) - \log(1-pB)).$$ This should reduce to:

$$=\log\left(\frac{1-pB}{1-pA}\right)$$

When the correct answer is that depression is absent:
$$=(\log(0) - \log(pA)) - (\log(0) - \log(pB)).$$

I think that might reduce to the following, since the undefined $=\log(0)$ terms cancel each other out:

$$=\log\left(\frac{pB}{pA} \right)$$

But I'm not sure if the${}=\log(0)$ terms can actual cancel each other out here.

Are these the correct formulas or am I wrong? Is this the correct way to calculate the difference in log-odds between two logistic regression models?